# Get an Array by selection of a block from xml-File

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I have to write a program using Linq. I'm just a student and I didn't learned that yet, so I have two questions:

1. What would be a good book/ebook... to teach myself what my next question will be about?
2. I have an XML-File, that looks like this:

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <Projects>
      <Project>
          <Information>
          <Name>Project1</Name>
          <Date>26.01.2015</Date>
          </Information>
          <Files ID = "S" path = "C:\Users\marcel\Documents">
              <file>Test1.txt</file>
              <file>Test2.txt</file>
              <file>Test3.txt</file>
              <file>Test4.txt</file>
              <file>Test5.txt</file>
          </Files>
          <Files ID = "C" path = "C:\Users\marcel\Documents">
              <file>Test1(1).txt</file>
              <file>Test1(2).txt</file>
              <file>Test1(3).txt</file>
              <file>Test1(4).txt</file>
              <file>Test1(5).txt</file>
          </Files>
      </Project>
   ```

I want to get a string-array which is containing the values of the "file" elements, depenging on ID=S or C.
I have more than 1 project in there, so it first has to be searched by name, that's working right now:

```
var entries = from items in xelement.Elements("Project")
               where (string)items.Element("Name").Value == projectName
               select items;
```

that gets me the whole block of the needed project.
Can I use the result of the first command for getting the filenames?
Or can  I just extend the code of the first part?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get a specific `Project` element having the specified name you can use `First`:

```
var projectElement = xElement
  .Elements("Project")
  .First(x => (String) x.Element("Information").Element("Name").Value == projectName);
```

In a similar way you can find the desired `Files` element by specifying a value for the ID attribute:

```
var filesElement = projectElement
  .Elements("Files")
  .First(x => x.Attribute("ID").Value == id);
```

You can then use `Select` to project the `File` elements to their values and convert that to an array:

```
var files = filesElement
  .Elements("file")
  .Select(x => (String) x.Value)
  .ToArray();
```

Note that this code will throw exceptions if the XML has an unexpected format. E.g., if `First` does not find a matching element an exception is thrown. Also, the `Element` method will return `null` if the specified element is not found and thus code like `x.Element("Information").Element("Name")` will throw an exception if there is no `Information` element because the next call to `Element` is performed on the `null` reference.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Martin, that worked :)
I just came up with an own solution looking like this:

```
var files = from file in entries.Elements("Files").Elements("file")
                        where (string)file.Parent.Attribute("ID").Value == cOrS
                        select file.Value;
```